# can't be able to print whole div including (X symbol some delete button at the start for line and name of files in same line etc)

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to upload multiples files by selecting one by one at a time from computer or anywhere given uploaded path. I am able to select one by and in the same page i print it down under the Selected Documents but when i want to show down on the same page its print X symbol as delete button and next to X symbol i printed the name of file which i want to upload, i can upload multiple files at same time and show those multiple file on same page as selected documents for overview. but my X symbol is overlapping each other not showing in new line

at top of the same page i have upload button which select file and print down as i show.

```
| Delete | Name Of file | status       | Action | Status       |  
|------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------ | ------------ |  
| (X)    | File A       | Radio button | save   | approv or no |
| (X)    | File A       | Radio button | save   | approv or no |
| (X)    | File A       | Radio button | save   | approv or no |
```

some thing like this i want, but when i want to show x with circle around(i use border radius 100%) its show me on x for each line in same circle and not separate line but same print inside same circle downward and rest of the things same overlapping as well

Angular code

```
export class FileComponent implements OnInit {
  result: any = '';
  deleteMee: any = '';
  selectedFile: File = null;


  onSelectedFile(event: any): void {
    let selectedFile = event.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      this.deleteMee += "X"; //i want this as delete symbol with whole circle around
      this.deleteMee = "<br />";
      this.result += selectedFile[i].name
      // select file for show down in the page
      // for later save it to a db via api
      this.result += "<br />"
    }
  }

  uploadFile() {
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('name', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post('api here', fd).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}


<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h2> Selected Files
    </>
    <header>
      <div>
        <div id="delete">
          <h2 class="h2--custom-size">Delete</h2>
        </div>
        <div id=" fileName">
          <h2 class="h2--custom-size">File Name</h2>
        </div>
        <div id=" status">
          <h2 class="h2--custom-size">FileStatus</h2>
        </div>
        <div id=" action">
          <h2 class="h2--custom-size">Actions</h2>
        </div>
        <div id=" status">
          <h2 class="h2--custom-size">Status</h2>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id=" undertText">
      <div><span [innerHTML]="deleteMee"></span></div>
      <div><span [innerHTML]="result"></span></div>
      <div> <input type="radio" id="approve" name="approve">
        <label for="value">Approve</label>
      </div>
      <div> <input type="button" id="save" name="save">
        <label for="value">Save</label>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want to have top heading text with the Delete File Name Status Action Status
 and under those heading text want to print (X) as delete button File name radio button and so on.... As i showed in under the Provide background and what i have tried......

Answer (score 0):

For the X button you can use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) or a button like `<button class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius:50%">X</button>`

Also for showing results in lines you should try using [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for better alignment of your elements. Basically your line should be wrapped by a `<div class="row">...</div>` and using `<div class="col-..."></div>`.

You can also try using a table with *ngFor for the display of files
For example

```
export class Result{
    fileName:string;
    //other atributes
}

result:Result[] = new Array<Result>();
result.Add({fileName:"file",...}); //each file you want to upload

<table>
    <thead>
        //headers go here
        <tr>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>File Name</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        //body goes here
        <tr *ngFor="let file of result">
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius:50%">X</button></td>
            <td>{{file.fileName}}</td> 

            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but this solution is not working for me, I have upload file button from there i select file one by one and add result inside leveranskomponent one by one and show each file down inside div as you mentioned inside table, but the solution is not working for me, my logic is little bit complex, I was able to print inside div or table but the problems i faced is not new line as show in the question above, the X was printing inside same border.If you could see above i am showing whole output in proper formatted, that's what i want. my logic i working but problem in proper formatted output

Comment: The problem is that you are adding all X in the same div, my suggestion is to not alter the dom during the function as it is very difficult to get the result you want. The best approach is to first create the output and then display it dynamically using Angular directives (see [Angular-Displaying Data](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)) as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: can some one has another solution of my problem? I am still stack with this problem, this is requirement, I can not loop to X button inside div, because i select file one by one from my upload file and add down inside div one by one. I have X button which is use to delete whole record or line for every file i added must be able to delete as required , that's why i need X button type at the start of line. exact as ouput shown above in question

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for the question, that i asked here

`export class FileComponent implements OnInit
        {
            arrayOfFiles = [];

```
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient ) { }

        onSelectedFile(event :any) :void 

                                         {

        var selectedFiles = event.target.files;

        console.log(selectedFiles[0])

        let fileObject =   
                         {
                          name: selectedFiles[0].name,
                          size: selectedFiles[0].size
                         };

        if(!!fileObject) 
                        {
                           this.arrayOfFiles.push(fileObject)
                           console.log(this.arrayOfFiles)
                        }
      }`
          `<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <li *ngFor="let file of arrayOfFiles; let i = index">
                    <span>{{file.name}}</span>
                    </li>
              </div>`
```